# How to maintain upper left corner with skew, without using transform?

Tags: javascript, css

This may be more of a math question, but I am looking for any tips/tricks to get this done. First - I am using our in-house graphical engine which is very similar to HTML and CSS, but has severe limitations.

***Long question, short - how do I find the left attribute of a rectangle, knowing its upper left corner, skew angle and height?***

I need to extrude a line into a 3D surface. I am attempting to simply create a rectangle, and then add a skew. We have skew, scale, and translate. **THAT IS IT.** Skew seems to work well to display the image how I want, but I cannot get the origin/anchor/whatever as I want it. I feel there has to be a mathematical solution to this, but I cannot figure it out.

Basically I need to set the left position of the rectangle to the correct spot, based on the angle of the skew, the X1 attribute of the line, and the desired height of the rectangle. My first attempt was to simply use the rotation matrix to find the lower left corner, and then set the `left` attribute to the midpoint of that point and the original X1 attribute of the line. This is off by a slight amount - enough to be annoying.

Here is the relevant JS:

```
function hover(evt) {
    var TgmlDoc = evt.getCurrentTarget().getOwnerDocument();
    var TgmlElem = TgmlDoc.getDocumentElement();
    var rect = TgmlDoc.createElement("Rectangle");

    theLeft = evt.getCurrentTarget().getAttribute('X1');
    theTop = evt.getCurrentTarget().getAttribute('Y1');
    theWidth = evt.getCurrentTarget().getAttribute('X2') - theLeft;
    theHeight = 30;

    theLeft = (+theLeft + theLeft*Math.cos(238*Math.PI/180) - theTop*Math.sin(238*Math.PI/180))/2;

    console.log(theLeft);
    console.log(theTop);
    console.log(theWidth);
    console.log(theHeight);

    var theSkew = TgmlDoc.createElement("SkewX");
    theSkew.setAttribute("Angle","-58");
    rect.appendChild(theSkew);

    rect.setAttribute("Left", theLeft);
    rect.setAttribute("Top", theTop);
    rect.setAttribute("Width", theWidth);
    rect.setAttribute("Height", theHeight);
    rect.setAttribute('Opacity','0.5');
    rect.appendChild(theSkew);
    TgmlElem.appendChild(rect); 
}
```

And the result (original line is red), which is slightly off:

[image]

Also, as an aside - making the height equal to 40 makes this work perfectly. I cannot figure out why the height has anything to do with it, but it does.

Comment: are you aware about `transform-origin` ? You make it `top` and everything will be easy in your case

Comment: I cannot use transform or any of its kin.

Comment: you are applying a skew and there is necessarely an origin. Either you can adjust it or it's by default something. We need to at least know the origin

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50700690/8620333 .. you need to use tangent and yes the height is important.

Comment: The skew is being applied to the rectangle. It appears to be around the center. I have no more information than that.

Comment: if we assume the 'origin' to be the center, I would imagine it is (450,535) (using the dimensions I already provided). I guess we need to move it, then get the new left. Does that make sense? I will adjust to above code to reflect what I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199910/discussion-between-lukehawk-and-temani-afif).

Comment: I am closing as duplicate since the other answer contain the formula you needed